# Eclipse formatter JUST indenting

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to set the Eclipse formatter to only do the indenting?  To leave everything else alone?

I do not really care about a space here or there, and indeed sometimes like to add them, eg after a !.  But I do care about lots of spurious line changes in source control.

(I suspect the answer is no.  I am not talking about changing specific options.  Just turning everything except indenting off.  Do not touch.  Do not change spacing.  Do not un/wrap lines. Just the indenting.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you talk about indenting Java code, there is the command ***Correct Indentation*** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> for that (also contained in the main menu *Source*, in the Java editor right-click menu *Source* and via Quick Access <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>).

Comment: Thanks, but Ctrl-I does a complete reformat.  I was looking for something to just do the indents.  Incidentally, why not use the Microsoft style shortcuts that run directly off the menus and do not need to be memorized -- Alt-s-f.  The one good thing about MS UIs.

Comment: _Correct Indentation_ does not format, but only indent the code. The shortcuts can be changed in _Window > Preferences: General > Keys_. _Correct Indentation_ can also be automatically executed on save as so-called [_save action_](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-06/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/editor/ref-preferences-save-actions.htm?cp=1_4_4_0_5_4).